# WebView HTML5 Video or 3D renderer cropped of Android < 4.1

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I use WebView widget in my project to display HTML5 videos or different content in HTML5 or not. I have no problem to render these HTML5 pages (using video or not) if my WebView is in `MATCH_PARENT` and fit my screen device.

A problem occurred when I see HTML5 video and other HTML5 elements (using 3D properties? checking progress...) in WebView with fixed size. I suppose that my problem occurred when the WebView renders some elements ​​on the `SurfaceView` which causes a shift of content when the WebView layout param isn't `MATCH_PARENT`.

Let me explain with an example, consider a device in 800 * 600, I decided to center my webview which has a width of 400px. So I can see 100px to the right and 100px to the left of my webview, normal.
I see my HTML5 video cropped to the right. The width of the crop is the offset between the left border of the screen and the left of the webview.
If I increase the space to the left of the webview, the crop will be have the same value of this space.

From youtube page, the HTML5 content is displayed correctly with the same size of my webview but just my video HTML5 element is cropped ...
For a better understanding, I let you see the screenshots that will be more understandable ...

http://android.googlecode.com/issues/attachment?aid=405500000000&name=webviewhtml5-vimeo-cropped.png&token=2lYIR8vnq0aGAHjQ4Ppvj9bs6hg%3A1354812792302&inline=1

The problem appears from Android 3.x to 4.0.x. From Nexus S phone running Android 4.1 and Samsung Galaxy S III Android 4.1, the problem is solved.

I am surprised to find no one who has reported this problem on the bugreport or stackoverflow? Generally, I think the webview is used in fullscreen.

If you can reproduce this problem with a basic project, go to this address :

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40550

Comment: I had a similar issue, and didn't have much luck solving it. I did post a possible workaround, but it doesn't fix the real problem. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13080578/931277. I'll be interested to see how you solve it :)